# Python: Printing data and receiving user input simultaneously

Tags: python-3.x

I want to be able to receive user input and print stuff simultaneously, without them interfering. Ideally, that would be printing regularly and having the user type input to the bottom of the terminal window, for example:

```
printed line
printed line
printed line
printed line
printed line
(this is where the next print would happen)


Enter Input: writing a new input...
```

This should look  like a chat app or something of that sort.
If there is no good way to do that, any  way to print above the input line would be amazing too.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at curses? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it is not very feasible to both take input and give output in python, without importing modules to directly interact with the OS.
But you can can get pretty close to it with this code:

```
import curses
import random # for random messages

#this should be async
def get_message(): 
    message = [str(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(15)]
    return "".join(message)
def handle_command(cmd): # handle commands
    if cmd=="exit":
        exit(0)

def handle_message(msg): # send a message
    raise NotImplementedError

def draw_menu(stdscr):
    stdscr.erase()
    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.raw()
    k = 0
    typed=""
    while True:
        # Initialization
        stdscr.erase()
        height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Welcome to chat app")
        msg = get_message()
        if msg: # add a message if it exists
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, msg)
        if k==ord("\n"): # submit on enter
            if typed.startswith("/"): # execute a command
                typed = typed[1:]
                handle_command(typed)
            elif typed.startswith("./"): # bypass commands with a dot
                typed = typed[1:]
                handle_message(typed)
            else:
                handle_message(typed) # send the message
            typed = ""
        elif k==263: # Backspace
            typed = typed[:-1] # erase last character 
            stdscr.addstr(height-1, 0, typed)
        elif k==3: # Ctr+C
            typed="" # Delete the whole string
            stdscr.addstr(height-1, 0, typed)
        elif k!=0:
            typed += chr(k) # add the char to the string
            stdscr.addstr(height-1, 0, typed)
        stdscr.refresh() # refresh 

        # Wait for next input
        k = stdscr.getch()


def main():
    curses.wrapper(draw_menu)


if __name__ == "__main__": # dont import
    main()
```

the only thing that is to do to update the messages is to type a new char.
And **I do not recommend you to build a chat in the terminal for anything other then educational value (trust me I tried it).**
It would be better if you tried it using a web platform (e.g. [Tauri](https://tauri.app) or [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org))

Also the code cannot:

- insert automatic line breaks (it errors)
- send any messages (must implement yourself)
- show any user names (must implement yourself)